# Find the following limit by L'Hopital Rule: $\lim_{x\to 0} (1-x) ^{1/x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x\to 0} (1-x) ^{1/x}$

I know it might need to use $e$ to get the answer. 
But still need some help.

Comment: Try taking the logarithm of the limit.

Comment: let $y=1/x$, and use $e=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lim_{x \to 0} (1-x)^{1/x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \exp{ \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}} = \exp({\lim_{x\to 0}} \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}) = \exp(-1)=e^{-1}$ (since $\lim{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x} = -1$)

Comment: Note that the second equality holds because $\exp$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Without using L'Hopital's Rule:

Let $y=1/x$

Then, noting that $x = 1/y$, $$\lim_{x \to 0} (1-x)^{1/x} = \lim_{y \to \infty} \left(1-1/y\right)^y = \frac 1 e$$

Where the last equality is a commonly known [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_representations_of_e).

Comment: Little bit picky, but if it's $\lim_{x\to0}$, then it should translate to $\lim_{\vert y \vert \to \infty}$, as $x$ could approach $0$ from either side. Conclusion remains the same though.